# Convert STEP file to mold file

Tags: molds

I need to turn a prototype into a mold. Conventional metal molds are too expensive.  I have the STEP files of the prototype. Is there anyone here that does that?

Comment: Glad you are here but this is not the type of site that you are thinking of. It is a question/answer site to solve issues with 3D printing. The site does not offer services. Also, please be careful when putting personal or business information out on a publically accessible site.

Comment: HI and welcome. Please [edit] your question, rewording it to ask how to do what you want to do, else it may end up being get deleted. As agarza has already stated no services are provided on this site and requests for recommendations for services are off-topic.

Comment: If you already have the STEP file, you can load that file in a CAD program to create the mold yourself. You do need to add an interface to pour or inject the material you want to make the prototype from (also add an overflow opening, depending on the product). I think [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11496/) answers your question.

Comment: most CAD software will let you subtract one shape from another producing a negative that can resemble a mold.  Depending on the geometry you need and the material you intend to use, you will need to make multiple pieces of the mold and alter features for easy removal.